# spring boot distributed processing with kafka

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-integration

I have several apps developed using spring boot. Some apps call another apps, that in time call other apps, it is getting hard to manage and scale. I need to be able to distribute them in a network and also combine the apps in different 'flows' with minimun changes to the apps.

Ideally I would like to wrap the apps and abstract them into components that have N inputs and M outputs. At boot time I would use some configuration to wire the inputs and outputs to real kafka topic queues. 
 For instance, input A to an app can come from several kafka topic queues, and the output B from the same app can go to other set of kafka topic queues.

I would like to be able to change the queues without having to recompile the apps, also no extra network hops to send/receive from/to multiple queues, this should in the same process and multi threaded.

Does anybody knows if something similar exists already? Can spring integration do this? Apache Camel? Or am I better off writing it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Spring for Apache Kafka](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/). There is also a spring-integration-kafka extension that sits on top of spring-kafka.

> The Spring for Apache Kafka (`spring-kafka`) project applies core Spring concepts to the development of Kafka-based messaging solutions. It provides a "template" as a high-level abstraction for sending messages. It also provides support for Message-driven POJOs with `@KafkaListener` annotations and a "listener container". These libraries promote the use of dependency injection and declarative. In all of these cases, you will see similarities to the JMS support in the Spring Framework and RabbitMQ support in Spring AMQP.

Comment: thanks Gary! would the @KafkaListener allow me to decide at run time what topic(s) to listen subscribe to? Would it start threads (pool) for each topic? if yes, any sample at hand, if not, does it make sense the overhead or going straight to kafka-client

Comment: I just read the basic docs at Spring For Apache kafka, it seems to use threads, and that it might be possible to build this framework using a KStream as in the very basic example at https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#_kafka_streams_example  not sure how to support multiple "kstreams" in the same app...

Comment: With `@KafkaListener` there's a thread per consumer; consumers are defined by the `concurrency` setting; consumers (containers) can subscribe to multiple topics but that doesn't affect threading. Yes, the topics can be configured using properties. There are lots of examples in `EnableKafkaIntegratioTests`. The framework doesn't do much for streams, except providing a factory bean for the `StreamsBuilder` and spring context lifecycle management. Yes, you can have multiple KStreams in an app.

Comment: I like it, marking as answer... only need to figure out how to use kryo instead of json... but it seems to support MessageConverter...thanks!

Comment: Boot has autoconfig and property support fir spring-kafka too. See the boot docs.

Comment: It can be done in camel. 

You need to externalize the URIs for the producers and consumers. You could use YML files to configure the structures like this:

    @ConfigurationProperties
    public class CamelEndpointConfiguration {
    
      private String from;
      private String to;
    
      // Getters and setters
    
    }


Also if you get more fancy, you could have a route definition class that you could instance everytime you need another set of input/output with different brokers/topics to interact with. This can all be done in runtime (I done all this)

Comment: I have created a first draft using just the kafka client. See at https://github.com/kalvarez2/distProcess

Comment: The problem is not to change the input or output queue. The problems is to be able use and application designed to write to queue "blah" and make it send the messages instead to q1, q2 and q3, without making code changes.